# Why i++ happened first?

Tags: java

I tried below code with result `{2,3,3}`. I cannot explain why first element's value's been changed. I suppose it is aliasing effect, but confused.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int i = 0;
while (i < arr.length - 1) {
    arr[i++] = arr[i];
}
i = 0;
while (i < arr.length) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*alias effect*"?

Comment: I cannot explain the result. I know my thought maybe wrong, thus wait here for correct explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the first element is changed to the value of the second element because the line `arr[i++] = arr[i];` is actually executed as this:

`arr[0] = arr[1]`

That means the first value of the array is set to the second (remember indexing of arrays start at 0) of the array which is 2 in this case. The `++` operator increments the counter only after using it the first time as the actual value without incrementing it.

After the first loop trough the first while loop your array looks like this: `[2,2,3]` with `i` being `1` Then `arr[1] = arr[2]` is getting executed which changes the array to: `[2,3,3]` with `i` being `2`

That is the final result.

Comment: Why i increment cannot wait for the finish of that line? I think it is one command and i could increment after the command is executed.

Comment: The incremention of i happens right after the use of i++. So first the array at position i gets accessed, then i is getting incremented and the array at position i+1 gets accessed in the second part of the statement.

Comment: Also worth referencing ["The Java Tutorials > Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) and [JLS § 15.14.2: Postfix Increment Operator ++"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)

Answer (score 0):

If we step through the first loop (arr.length = 3)

```
first: i < 3 - 1 : 0 < 2 => true
arr[0] (increments i, i is now 1) = arr[1] =>  arr[0] = 2;
arr is now {2, 2, 3}

second time in loop: i < 3 - 1 : 1 <  2 => true
arr[1] (increments i, i is now 2) = arr[2] => arr[1] = 3
arr is now {2, 3, 3}

third loop check: i < 3 - 1 : 2 < 2: false; exit while loop;

Print out array: {2, 3, 3}
```

Comment: Why i increment cannot wait for the finish of that line? I think it is one command and i could increment after the command is executed